# How an activity is visible once i press home button and relaunch the activity?

Tags: android

I want to know How an activity is visible once i press home button and relaunch the activity

for eg. If an application went in background and lauch again then MyActicity.java should be visible and not the same screen on which I quit.

Please suggest the possible solution

Thanks
Monali

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html   Especially about lifecycle

Comment: Thanks to all...my problem is solved by writing android:launchMode="singleTask" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" property in manifest file

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) the onPause() method is called, whenever your Activity is paused. Just put this code in your Activity code:

```
public void onPause() {
    this.finish();
}
```

If you do so, the Activity will be closed, whenever it is paused.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well your questions but if you have 2 activities A and B. if you are in B and press home button and then when you return to the app you want to go to A.. you have to call finish() method inside onPause() method on Activity B.